# Does Google charge you for usage of the Google Analytics API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, price

I am using google analytics reporting api, from [API Limits and Quotas](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/limits-quotas)
I get the quota as below:

> 50,000 requests per project per day, which can be increased.
>   10 queries per second (QPS) per IP.

Is this quota for free? From my developer console, i got reminder.

[image]

I don't understand what's the $300 in credit mean. Dose it mean i need to pay $300 after my free trail? Thanks

Comment: check this out http://www.blastam.com/google-analytics-comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Analytics API is free to use.  You don't have to pay for using it.   If you run out of [quota](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/limits-quotas) you can request an increase on the 50000 requests a day.  I recommend requesting the increase when you are using around 80% of your current quota because it can take sometime to get the increase.    You don't have to pay for the increase.

Your $300 credit can be used for other Google offerings like cloud servers and stuff.